# What's the meaning of "push through"? (Could you please explain it in the text below?)

Tags: meaning

The main text is: People who wear exercise watches become trapped in a cycle of escalation. 10000 steps may have been the gold standard last week, but this week it's 11000. Next week, 12000 ... That trend can't continue forever, but many people **push through** stress fractures and other major injuries to seek the same endorphin high that came from a much lighter exercise load only months earlier.

Comment: Push through means surpass, to push so hard as to get to the other side.  If you ignore pain, and pass through it to enjoy other benefits, you have traveled 'into and out of' the barrier.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more in the line of "continuing despite of".

more like, "many people are pushing their way through stress fractures and other major injuries to seek the same endorphin high"

intuitive enough?

Comment: To a certain extent.

Comment: In defense of my interpretation, I'd ask you to look at the argument. The paper(or whatever it is) is arguing 'against' the exercise watches. So push through is not the usual idiomatic dictionary meaning of "passing your way **towards** a beneficial state" but "**enduring**, pushing your way through something unpleasant". I think!

Comment: And what is the relationship between your interpretation and the last sentence ( to seek the same endorphin high that came from a much lighter exercise load only months earlier)?

Comment: exactly that. The high which once came from from a much lighter exercise now has to come from a higher load,.. load high enough to cause stress fractures n stuff which people are pushing through.

Answer (score 0):

> Many people push through stress fractures and other major injuries to seek the same endorphin high that came from a much lighter exercise load only months earlier.

It's related to *push through the crowd*, meaning to force your way through, and *get through*, [which is](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/get-through) to "get through something to manage to deal with a difficult situation or to stay alive until it is over -- *The refugees will need help to get through the winter; I just have to get through the first five minutes of my speech, and then I’ll be fine.*"  But with "push through," the connotation isn't just of persistence -- there's also forcefulness and making a quantum leap.  I haven't been able to find the new use of "push through" in any dictionaries.  But here are some examples taken from articles about exercising and working out:

> [8 Ways to Override the Urge to Quit](http://www.shape.com/weight-loss/tips-plans/8-ways-override-urge-quit): When you want to give in, use these tips to push through that mental block and safely finish the most challenging workouts
>
> [Science-Backed Ways to Push Through Workout Fatigue](http://www.shape.com/fitness/tips/science-backed-ways-push-through-workout-fatigue): Don't let a workout wall stop you from achieving the body breakthrough you've been sweating for.
>
> [How Much Is Too Much?: When Not to Push Through Exercise](http://journals.lww.com/acsm-healthfitness/Fulltext/2014/11000/How_Much_Is_Too_Much___When_Not_to_Push_Through.10.aspx): ... For every individual, there is an activity threshold beyond which pain and injury occur. If this is exceeded, downtime from exercise necessarily occurs, and the exercise training effect and other health benefits obviously stop accruing. Sports medicine physicians spend a substantial proportion of their daily practice dealing with individuals who have pushed too hard and exceeded this threshold.
>
> 23 Ways to Push Through a Tough Workout: ... There are ways to push through the invisible wall and squeeze every last drop out of a workout.

Your sentence means that people persist in exercising, despite an injury, hoping that they can get past the discomfort through sheer willpower.